# curl issue: How to post json format data to server using curl in windows cmd?

Tags: json, curl, post

After posting json format data to server using `curl` in windows command prompt(cmd), I'm testing the response data now, got a 'Bad request' message.
I've checked the request format, too.

cmd:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "isbn":"123442123, 97885654453443","title":"Learn how to build modern web application with MEAN stack","author": "Didin J.","description":"The comprehensive step by step tutorial on how to build MEAN (MongoDB, Express.js, Angular 5 and Node.js) stack web application from scratch","published_year":"2017","publisher":"Djamware.com" }' localhost:3000/api
```

And then,

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 11
ETag: W/"b-EFiDB1U+dmqzx9Mo2UjcZ1SJPO8"
Date: Wed, 05 Sep 2018 01:41:55 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Bad Request
```

What's wrong? please help me.

Comment: are you posting json data to your own webserver?

Comment: yes, I send the json data to localhost.
`curl: (3) Port number out of range
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'T'
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 11
ETag: W/"b-EFiDB1U+dmqzx9Mo2UjcZ1SJPO8"
Date: Thu, 06 Sep 2018 01:02:41 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Bad Request`
That shows to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote the title as 'curl issue...', but i think curl has never any issue, because it is very widely used.

And your request data have no fault.

As my experience, problem would be exist in DB connection.

**please check and check the accuracy of MongoDB connection.**

Comment: Ok, well done.
The result:
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
ETag: W/"2-l9Fw4VUO7kr8CvBlt4zaMCqXZ0w"
Date: Thu, 06 Sep 2018 01:05:16 GMT
Connection: keep-alive`
Thanks.
Great help.